# Jquery mobile and meteor reactive template variables not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, meteor

When I have a template variable, and I change it, the screen goes white and it goes blank.

heres a simple example:

```
{{#if var}}
<p align="center">reactive templating</p>
<button id="button" value="click"/>
{{else}}
<p align="center">worked!</p>
{{/if}} 




Session.setDefault("var",true);

  Template.content.var = function () {
    return Session.get("var");
  }

  Template.content.events({
    'click #button': function(e,t) {
      Session.set("var", false);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that I have

```
<body>
{{>content}}
</body>
```

so it re-renders the whole page, including the page divs.

So do this instead...

```
<body>
<div data-role="page">
{{>content}}
</div>
</body>
```